# clone, update and prepend div

Tags: jquery

I have a page where users can post questions. Whenever a new question is posted I am cloning the div , updating it with new values and then prepending the div on top of of all the previous divs.This is my code:

```
var lastDiv = $("#divAll div:last").clone();     
$("[id$='_imgPostAll']",lastDiv).attr("ImageUrl",post.d.sImageURL);
$("[id$='_lblNameAll']",lastDiv).html(post.d.sNickName); 
$("[id$='_lblTimeAll']",lastDiv).html(post.d.sDate);
$("[id$='_lblShareAll']",lastDiv).html(post.d.sShareComment);   
$("#divAll").prepend(lastDiv);
$("#divAll div:last").show("slow");`
```

The updated div is not showing up on the page. But when I replace var lastDiv = $("#divAll div:last").clone() with var lastDiv = $("#divAll").clone(), the updated div appears but it appears twice, thrice depending on the previous divs. I only want it to clone the last div and update it with new values rather than all the previous divs.

Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't you use any code behind file for this?

Comment: Isn't there any database updation?

Comment: Can you show the HTML you are using...?

Comment: Yes there is a databae updation too. and the result is a JSON string from a webservice. Everything is a working fine. The problem is only with the div cloning.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you clone the div, the name attribute is copied with the clone.  So when you later retrieve the div for recloning, you inadvertently grab the copies you've already made as well as the original.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to get at.  One concern is that it the way you describe the behavior you are trying to update the new div.  But your updates are not targetted to the div you cloned.

Comment: Hey can u tell me the procedure to update the div which is cloned. I am going wrong with the syntax. Thanks.

Comment: You've stored the result of .clone() in lastDiv, so access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line reads:

```
$("#divAll div:last").show("slow");`
```

But you are prepending your cloned div to the container, so the cloned div will appear first.

Show the first div instead:

```
$("#divAll div:first").show("slow");`
```

or even better, simply show the cloned div directly:

```
lastDiv.show("slow");
```